# Website is not loading styles and files because is loading a different path

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I just published my web app which has the following structure:

- Project Name

  - StylesFolder

    - filename.css
    - anotherfile.css
  - JavaScriptFolder

    - bootstrap.js
  - Index.html

What I did was:

1. Adding a new WebSite in the server IIS with the path were I publish my WebApp (ex. C:\WebProjects\PublishedApp\Project Portal)
2. Selecting my published app and converting into an application (The alias name was Project Name and the physical path was C:\WebProjects\PublishedApp\Project Portal\Project Name)

The problem is when I try to see the website. I'm able to enter to 192.169.100.20:80/Project%Name/ and my index page is loaded (I can see the text, inputs, etc.) but I cannot see any stlye and javascript input and when I check the console logs all the files are getting a 404 error response.

When I check which URL is used by the files I can see that they are trying to get accessed by 192.169.100.20:80/Project Name/StylesFolder/filename.css etc...

So my question is what can I do to remove the /Project%Name/ string from the URL?

**PD. I'm using IIS 7**

Comment: Publish your app to the root of that web site, not an IIS application under the site.

Answer (score 0):

When you add your website in IIS, select the application folder you published. For example, when you publish your application to D:\Program Files\Publish Folder, select the Publish Folder folder directly when adding the website and choose the physical path.

This is the reference:[Deploy Website on IIS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/steps-to-deploy-website-on-iis/)